# Cannot see reusable workflow after activate the feature

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, reusable

I am using SP2013 standard and Sharepoint designer 2013
I created a reusable workflow in a site collection. It only contains one step which is send an email to "this item" creator. 
Using SPD I saved the workflow as template, download it, import it to another site as solution, activate the solution. In the new site "site feature" I activate the feature.

However, I cannot see the workflow in "workflow settings". I cannot add a new workflow using it as template. But when I connect SPD to new site I can see it in workflow list. When I click "associate it with list" button in SPD, IE prompt up to "Add a workflow" page. But it doesn't work because the workflow not listed in "workflow template"...

What is going wrong?

Comment: After publish the Global still, it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way: Associate it from SPD, the option should be available in the ribbon when you have selected your workflow in SPD. Probably it will show you some options (Lists I suppose) and you will immediately see if it is possible to associate your workflow to that list or not.

In case the workflow cannot be associated to the list you want to associate it to, this can be because of several reasons:

I'm not familiar with 2013 workflows, but the gist of Reusable Workflows is: Reusable workflows are usually either Site(?) or Content Type workflows (List Workflows are not reusable), as they need to be "Reusable", i.e. they use properties that are defined in a common place and can be reused, which is why the workflow is also using this definition, which is what makes the workflow itself reusable. Content Types are reusable (you can create lists based on this content type) so Content Type workflows are also reusable. So looking in a list to associate the workflow is usually not enough, because the criteria for the workflow to show up there depend on how the reusable workflow was created.

To figure it out you can ask yourself the following questions:

What type is the reusable workflow (2010/ 2013) ? In case of 2010, what content type did you associate it with ? Does the list you want to associate the workflow to contain said Content Type ? When checking the List/Library to associate the workflow, did you make sure to select the correct content type first before looking in the list of possible workflows ?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have selected a content type that exists in both site collections, as Cameron stated. If so, then go into SharePoint Designer on the new site collection. The workflow should be there under reusable workflow. Open and publish it, and it will become available to associate.

Answer (score 0):

you should go to SharePoint Designer and chose Publish Globally and it will be shown there.